# What is the lowest iOS version developers can create an app for?

Tags: ios, ios-4.2, ios4, whatsapp, iphone-3g

Is it still possible to create an app for iOS 4.2.1 (or lower)???

The reason for this question is that Whatsapp is not available anymore for iOS < 4.3. This is what Whatsapp sais about this:

The latest version of WhatsApp for iPhone requires iOS 4.3 or later. Regretfully, Apple does not allow new app updates to be compatible with both iOS 6 and older versions of iOS, effectively ending support for iPhone 3G and the original iPhone. Because of Apple's policy change to new App Store submissions, there is nothing we can do at this time for users with older versions of iOS.

Comment: Technically the lowest version for official development is 2, though toolchains exist(ed) for unofficial development since the original iPhone came out. The "It's not possible to write apps to iOS 4.2" is just Apple's BS and brainless restriction in order everybody to buy the latest device (and to make jailbreaking harder).

Comment: If you want to support your application for iOS 6 then you cannot support the iOS version less than 4.2 coz Xcode 4.5 has no support for lesser version than iOS 4.2.

Comment: What Whatsapp say is correct, although there ways to include support for ARMv6 and there for iOS 4.* and even 3.* to your app. But this does include multiple binaries in one binaries (fat binary).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(A more complete [question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11344762/89035))*

## iOS Support Matrix v2.4

This version is updated and includes iOS 7.

[image: iOS Suport Matrix]

Link: http://www.iossupportmatrix.com

Answer (score 3):

With the Xcode version 4.5.x or later, you can not create the application for devices having iOS 4.3.

However iPhone starts with iOS 2. So with lower versions of Xcode and iOS SDK, you can build the applications for those versions as well. But its important when you want to support the iPhone5 with big screen.

With lower versions of iOS SDK, you can create the application which can support devices having iOS 4.* onwards. But with those applications, you can not take advantage of big screen of iPhone5.

Comment: I'm sure that it _is_ possible to create apps that support iOS 6 and all earlier ones but it's not simple and it's not really practical...

Answer (score 1):

According to the insert, only **updates** are excluded. Which means it is still possible to create apps for iOS 4.2.1 or lower. I just submitted an app about two weeks ago which was created using Xcode 4.5.1 and uses an sdk lower than 4.2.1 hassle-free.