# xcode 4.6 can't show deployment target 4.2

Tags: iphone, ios-4.2, deployment-target

i have xcode 4.6.It show deployment target upto 4.3.
i want to use 4.2 but it can't show.

what's step for it.

What's problem?

Comment: do u know answer for this?

Comment: what is that extraordinary reason why you still need to develop anything for iOS4.2? how many devices do run iOS4? the latest _unofficial_ statistics says about 80% of devices run iOS6, about 15% of devices runs iOS5, the rest runs iOS3 or iOS4. why do you want to develop an application for the less than 5% of devices?

Comment: You can look into this questions if you really need to support it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12619124/how-to-support-both-armv6-and-armv7s-for-release-build-in-xcode-4-5/12678077#12678077

Comment: i want to run application in iphone 3G and it's have ios 4.2.1.It can't upgrade to ios 5 or ios 6.

Comment: You can't use Xcode 4.6 and iOS SDk to build app for the iPhone 3G because it has an ARMv6 processor. The ARMv6 processor is no longer supported by iOS since version 6.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the lowest iOS version developers can create an app for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14069384/what-is-the-lowest-ios-version-developers-can-create-an-app-for)

Answer (score 2):

Xcode 4.6 and iOS 6 do not support iOS 4.2 and/or ARMv6. (ARMv6 devices being iPhone 1st and 3G and the iPod Touch 1g and 2g)

Since all devices that have an ARMv7 are able to run iOS 5 you should set you minimum to 4.3 or if possible iOS 5.0.

Comment: but what this link is saying? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12619124/how-to-support-both-armv6-and-armv7s-for-release-build-in-xcode-4-5/12678077#12678077

Comment: Then do that! This is not official and requires you to build the iOS 4.* version with an older version of Xcode and then use a later version of Xcode to build on fat binary which contain both the app (ARMv6 and ARMv7). You will need a lot on knonwledge about the farmeworks to do this correctly and setup you code with a lot of compiler directives. In short it is not worth you time, 90% are already running iOS 6 and only < 4% are running 4.2.